# Why deleting the rows using merge command is taking more time than delete statement in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

This is my scenario: I have a table `TableA` from which I have to archive the data into `TableB`. That is I have to delete the rows from `TableA` and insert the deleted rows into `TableB` for a given modifieddate (e.g. `2015-01-01`).

Now as the number of data rows to be deleted is 2 million, I have to delete the rows in chunks so as to minimize locking.

Out of the two methods I observed that simple `delete` statement was far better than the `merge` statement. `Delete` statement took 15 seconds to delete from `TableA` and insert the deleted records into `TableB`. However it took 7 min to complete the same task using the `merge` statement. Can someone tell me why ?

For reference please see my code below : -

```
-----------Merge statement--------------
declare @i int = 1

while @i > 0
begin
   begin try
   begin transaction
       merge top (1000) tableA as a
       using tableB as b on a.id = b.id

       when not matched by source and a.modifieddate = '2015-01-01' 
          then
             delete
             output deleted.id, deleted.column1, deleted.column2 into TableB(id, column1, column2);

       set @i =  @@rowcount

       if @@trancount > 0 
          commit transaction
   end try
   begin catch
       if @@trancount > 0 
          rollback transaction
   end catch
end
```

and now the delete statement:

```
----------------Delete statement--------
declare @i int = 1

while @i > 0
begin
    begin transaction

    delete top (1000) a
    output deleted.id, deleted.column1, deleted.column2 into TableB(id, column1, column2)
    from tableA as a
    where a.modifieddate = '2015-01-01' 

    set @i = @@rowcount

    if @@trancount > 0
       commit transaction
end
```

I have proper indexes on the column. `Columnd Id` has clustered index and column1, column2 have nonclustered indexes for `TableA` and `TableB` both.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong in my `Merge` statement and why it is taking so much more time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not easy to appreciate that... The best option will depend on many factors - table size, index complexity, frequency of occurrence etc... From other perspective you can also create an ON DELETE trigger that INSERTS the data into the new location as a reaction to the delete command that you execute.

Comment: If you can achieve your requirements using a simple `DELETE`, why are you complicating your life by trying to use `MERGE` instead?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. That's because I have quest to learn things and get the reason for the problems and not running away from them. I know that simple delete is easy and fast. But lets focus on the actual reason why there is a difference in performance

Comment: Idea/Tip: I would put an SQL Pprofile for both scenarios and capture and compare some perfomance metrics...CPU (ms), Reads ,Writes, Duration (ms) etc

Comment: You need to look at your query plan for this. The first query is doing some sort of lookup or table scan, which is going to be slower than the second query which is just deleting rows. Why dont you paste in your query plans, then someone can interpret.

Comment: Examine actual execution plan of both variants to understand what is going on. One obvious thing: `MERGE` joins two tables, `DELETE` doesn't.

Comment: The delete statement is not using tableB. The queries are not comparable in that way. You should achieve almost the same performance with both versions. What's the reason you are joining to tableB in the MERGE version? I don't understand what that is supposed to do.